# C++ Goodpractice for multiple derived class of the same base class

Tags: c++

Goal: I am making a program which has 10 pattern styles, which are implemented as different classes that derive from a common pattern base class.
The main.cpp creates a pattern style depending on the style chosen by the user.

The question:

how can main know about all pattern styles without creating so many headers?

ex : these will be the files if separated.

```
baseclass.h
baseclass.cpp
derivedclass1.h
derivedclass1.cpp
derivedclass2.h
derivedclass2.cpp
derivedclass3.h
derivedclass3.cpp
derivedclass4.h
derivedclass4.cpp
main.cpp
```

inside main.cpp:

```
#include "derivedclass1.h"
#include "derivedclass2.h"
#include "derivedclass3.h"
#include "derivedclass4.h"
```

Isn't this too much?

Is there a way to just call 1 namespace which has a list of of all derived class like unity (deriving in monobehavior)? i know it uses c# but still..

=====thoughts=====

Maybe a foreach loop that calls all derived class of the same base class? or should I make a `main_header.h` which `#include` all the style and include that from `main.cpp`?

Comment: including a single source file is too much. Dont include .cpp !

Comment: oh sorry it was supposed to be .h files

Answer (score 0):

Include header files, not .cpp files.

If you still need to include .cpp files for some reason: **Don't** (but rename it to _impl.h etc. for templates)

*Instead include header files*

```
#include "derivedclass1.h"
#include "derivedclass2.h"
#include "derivedclass3.h"
#include "derivedclass4.h"
```

If that seems too much: it is not a sin to put alike classes in the same file (albeit it should be a rare case):

*Then include that:*

```
#include "allderivedclasses.h"
```

Comment: sorry about that it was supposed to be .h file

Answer (score 0):

Your main concern seems to be "how can `main` know about all pattern styles?".
The answer is a factory function takes a pattern style name (and maybe some arguments) and produces the correct pattern style object. Each pattern style implementation is responsible for registering itself to the factory, such that `main` can remain oblivious.

For a more elaborate explanation of this technique, see https://dev.to/fenbf/factory-with-self-registering-types--35h1

In the code below, the `PatternStyle` class exposes two static functions:

- `register_pattern`: Each sub-class can register its name and a static constructor function at startup time into a `std::map pattern_styles`.
- `create`: Looks up the name in the `std::map` and invokes the constructor, if any.

**pattern_style.h**

```cpp
class PatternStyle {
...
public:
using Constructor = std::function<std::unique_ptr<PatternStyle>()>;
static std::unique_ptr<PatternStyle> create(const std::string& name);
static bool register_pattern(const std::string& name, Constructor ctor);
};
```

**pattern_style.cpp**

```cpp
static std::map<std::string, PatternStyle::Constructor> pattern_styles;

std::unique_ptr<PatternStyle> PatternStyle::create(const std::string& name) {
    auto it = pattern_styles.find(name);
    if (it == pattern_styles.cend())
        return {};
    else
        return it->second();
}

bool PatternStyle::register_pattern(const std::string& name, Constructor ctor) {
    pattern_styles[name] = ctor;
    return true;
}
```

This allows a subclass to register itself like so:

**wavy_pattern_style.h**

```cpp
class WavyPatternStyle : public PatternStyle {};
```

**wavy_pattern_style.cpp**

```cpp
static bool registration = PatternStyle::register_pattern("wavy", std::make_unique<WavyPatternStyle>);
```

Note: this use of `make_unique` requires C++14. If you only have C++11, you will need to make a dedicated constructor function (or use a lambda).

With this construct, it is a simple matter of defining pattern styles in separate files and including them in your build system, which solves your secondary concern.

Comment: I have read your reply.. updated the question and will get back after i try this... this is actually what I was looking for